# How to use Eigen FFT with MatrixXf?

Tags: c++, fft, eigen, eigen3

I am new to the Eigen library. I would like to compute FFT of Eigen Matrices. However, my attempts to do so indicate that the unsupported Eigen FFT module can't be used with MatrixXf. I want to pull off something like:

```
#include <eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/FFT>
#include<Eigen/Dense>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
int main(){
    MatrixXf A = MatrixXf::Random(3,10);
    FFT<float> fft;
    MatrixXf B;
    fft.fwd(B,A);
}
```

Is this achievable? Any other suggestions are welcome. It took me a great deal of self persuasion to migrate to Eigen from matlab, and I would prefer not using a different library unless it's inevitable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a reasonable expectation. Unfortunately in its current form, FFT does not support that exactly.

```
MatrixXcf B(3,10);  // note the change from real to complex
//fft.fwd(B,A); // It is natural to want to do this, unfortunately it is not yet supported

// it works to iterate over the columns
for (int k=0;k<A.cols();++k)
    B.col(k) = fft.fwd( A.col(k) );
```

Comment: Your code is not correct if one wants to compute a 2D FFT.  Why do you iterate over the columns but not over the rows?  See Saba's answer.

Comment: @wsw, the OP said nothing about 2D FFTs

Comment: Who is downvoting an accepted,correct answer?  Seriously, just because you don't _like_ the answer, doesn't make it "not useful".

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately it is not correct;

1) you have to iterate  on the rows of the input matrix (real)

2) then iterate over the columns of the output matrix (complex)

```
FFT<float> fft;
Eigen::Matrix<float, dim_x, dim_y> in = setMatrix();
Eigen::Matrix<complex<float>, dim_x, dim_y> out;

for (int k = 0; k < in.rows(); k++) {
    Eigen::Matrix<complex<float>, dim_x, 1> tmpOut;
    fft.fwd(tmpOut, in.row(k));
    out.row(k) = tmpOut;
}

for (int k = 0; k < in.cols(); k++) {
    Eigen::Matrix<complex<float>, 1, dim_y> tmpOut;
    fft.fwd(tmpOut, out.col(k));
    out.col(k) = tmpOut;
}
```

Comment: Your code is correct, which I tested against MATLAB's `fft2()` function.

Comment: I noticed two typos -- the temporary vectors `tmpOut` have the wrong lengths.  For example, the first one, where we iterate over the rows, should have a length of `dim_y`, because we are working on one row-vector at a time, whose length is `dim_y`.

Comment: how would the inverse transform work? start with iterating over the columns and then over the rows?

Comment: @JorritSmit: The order is irrelevant, you can apply to rows first or to columns first.

Comment: This answer no longer works with the default FFT solver in Eigen (kissfft, contributed by @mark-borgerding, who replied below) without replacing `in.row(k)` with `in.row(k).eval()`.  Otherwise, it produces `error: taking the address of a temporary object of type`.  After fixing this, if I use `complex<double>` input on a small magnitude 3 x 3 complex matrix, the answer only agrees with MATLAB and SciPy to a couple decimal places, but they agree with each other all the way.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting my answer that is based on Saba's.

```
std::shared_ptr< Eigen::MatrixXcf > Util::fft2(std::shared_ptr< Eigen::MatrixXf > matIn)
{
    const int nRows = matIn->rows();
    const int nCols = matIn->cols();

    Eigen::FFT< float > fft;
    std::shared_ptr< Eigen::MatrixXcf > matOut = std::make_shared< Eigen::MatrixXcf > (nRows, nCols);

    for (int k = 0; k < nRows; ++k) {
        Eigen::VectorXcf tmpOut(nCols);
        fft.fwd(tmpOut, matIn->row(k));
        matOut->row(k) = tmpOut;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < matOut->cols(); ++k) {
        Eigen::VectorXcf tmpOut(nRows);
        fft.fwd(tmpOut, matOut->col(k));
        matOut->col(k) = tmpOut;
    }

    return matOut;
}
```