# How to do FFT on MatrixXd in Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

It seems the code below is correct:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/FFT>

int main ()
{
    Eigen::FFT<float> fft;
    Eigen::Matrix<float, dim_x, dim_y> in = setMatrix();
    Eigen::Matrix<complex<float>, dim_x, dim_y> out;

    for (int k = 0; k < in.rows(); k++) {
        Eigen::Matrix<complex<float>, dim_x, 1> tmpOut;
        fft.fwd(tmpOut, in.row(k));
        out.row(k) = tmpOut;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < in.cols(); k++) {
        Eigen::Matrix<complex<float>, 1, dim_y> tmpOut;
        fft.fwd(tmpOut, out.col(k));
        out.col(k) = tmpOut;
    }
}
```

But this must specify the size of matrix in compile time, when I change the Matrix to MatrixXd, this has error when compiling. I want to know how could I do FFT on MatrixXd so I could specify the matrix size when it is running.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194451/how-to-use-eigen-fft-with-matrixxf/18534173

Comment: The code won't run as given because `dim_x` and `dim_y` aren't set.  If you set `dim_x` and `dim_y` to `-1` (or equivalently, `Eigen::Dynamic`), then you get dynamic sizes.  If you template those types out in a function then you get something that'll work no matter what the shape of the input is.  Though I find the default solver fails on size 0 or 1 inputs (which are just the identity under the FFT).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change all your variables to `Eigen::Dynamic` size instead of hard coding them and it should work. Or, use the built-in types as such:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/FFT>

int main ()
{
    size_t dim_x = 28, dim_y = 126;
    Eigen::FFT<float> fft;
    Eigen::MatrixXf in = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(dim_x, dim_y);
    Eigen::MatrixXcf out;
    out.setZero(dim_x, dim_y);

    for (int k = 0; k < in.rows(); k++) {
        Eigen::VectorXcf tmpOut(dim_x);
        fft.fwd(tmpOut, in.row(k));
        out.row(k) = tmpOut;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < in.cols(); k++) {
        Eigen::VectorXcf tmpOut(dim_y);
        fft.fwd(tmpOut, out.col(k));
        out.col(k) = tmpOut;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering！

Comment: This answer no longer works with the default Eigen FFT solver (kissfft), as it fails on the `in.row(k)` and `out.col(k)` with error: taking the address of a temporary object of type`.  You can fix with `in.row(k).eval()`, but I still only get 2 decimal places of agreement with MATLAB or SciPy when using `complex<double>` input types on a small scale matrix.