# Efficient pseudo-inverse for PyTorch 2D convolution

Tags: image-processing, pytorch, signal-processing, fft

**Background:**

Thanks for your attention! I am learning the basic knowledge of 2D convolution, linear algebra and PyTorch. I encounter the implementation problem about the psedo-inverse of the convolution operator. Specifically, I have no idea about how to implement it in an efficient way. Please see the following problem statements for details. Any help/tip/suggestion is welcomed.

(Thanks a lot for your attention!)

---

**The Original Problem:**

I have an image feature `x` with shape `[b,c,h,w]` and a `3x3` convolutional kernel `K` with shape `[c,c,3,3]`. There is `y = K * x`. How to implement the corresponding pseudo-inverse on `y` in an efficient way?

> There is [y = K * x = Ax], how to implement [x_hat = (A^+)y]?

I guess that there should be some operations using `torch.fft`. However, I still have no idea about how to implement it. I do not know if there exists an implementation previously.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

c = 32
K = torch.randn(c, c, 3, 3)
x = torch.randn(1, c, 128, 128)
y = F.conv2d(x, K, padding=1)

print(y.shape)

# How to implement pseudo-inverse for y = K * x in an efficient way?
```

---

**Some of My Efforts:**

I may know that the 2D convolution is a linear operator. It is equivalent to a "matrix product" operator. We can actually write out the matrix form of the convolution and calculate its psedo-inverse. However, I think this type of operation will be inefficient. And I have no idea about how to implement it in an efficient way.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse), the psedo-inverse may satisfy the property of `A(A_pinv(x))=x`, where `A` is the convolutional operator, `A_pinv` is its psedo-inverse, and `x` may be any image feature.

(Thanks again for reading such a long post!)

Comment: *Could you please complete the following code and give an example?* is not a proper question for this site. SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Hi @KenWhite, thanks for your kind reminder! Sorry, I posted the problem in a hurry without considering the appropriateness of the wordings and statements. I am now re-organizing the problem.

Comment: Look for “deconvolution”. There are a lot of answers on this site explaining how to do this. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48821963/7328782

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This takes the problem to another level.
The convolution itself is a linear operation, you can determine the matrix of the operation and solve a least square problem directly [[1]](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/84405/55891), or compute the pseudo-inverse as you mentioned, and then apply to different outputs and predicting a projection of the input.

I am changing your code to using `padding=0`

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

# your code
c = 32
K = torch.randn(c, c, 1, 1)
x = torch.randn(4, c, 128, 128)
y = F.conv2d(x, K, bias=torch.zeros((c,)))
```

Also, as you probably already suggested the convolution can be computed as `ifft(fft(h)*fft(x))`. However, the [conv2d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) function is a cross-correlation, so you have to conjugate the filter leading to `ifft(fft(h)*fft(x))`, also you have to apply this to two axes, and you have to make sure the FFT is calcuated using the same representation (size), since the data is real, we can apply [multi-dimensional real FFT](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.fft.rfftn.html). To be complete, [conv2d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) works on multiple channels, so we have to calculate summations of convolutions. Since the FFT is linear, we can simply compute the summations on the frequency domain
using [einsum](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html).

```py
s = y.shape[-2:]
K_f = torch.fft.rfftn(K, s)
x_f = torch.fft.rfftn(x, s)
y_f = torch.einsum('jkxy,ikxy->ijxy', K_f.conj(), x_f)
y_hat = torch.fft.irfftn(y_f, s)
```

Except for the borders it should be accurate (remember FFT computes a cyclic convolution).

```py
torch.max(abs(y_hat[:,:,:-2,:-2] - y[:,:,:,:]))
```

Now, notice the pattern `jk,ik->ij` on the `einsum`, that means `y_f[i,j] = sum(K_f[j,k] * x_f[i,k]) = x_f @ K_f.T`, if `@` is the matrix product on the first two dimensions. So to invert this operation we have to can interpret the first two dimensions as matrices. The function [pinv](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.linalg.pinv.html) will compute pseudo-inverses on the last two axes, so in order to use that we have to permute the axes. If we right multiply the output by the pseudo-inverse of transposed `K_f` we should invert this operation.

```py
s = 128,128
K_f = torch.fft.rfftn(K, s)
K_f_inv = torch.linalg.pinv(K_f.T).T
y_f = torch.fft.rfftn(y_hat, s)
x_f = torch.einsum('jkxy,ikxy->ijxy', K_f_inv.conj(), y_f)
x_hat = torch.fft.irfftn(x_f, s)
print(torch.mean((x - x_hat)**2) / torch.mean((x)**2))
```

Nottice that I am using the full convolution, but the conv2d actually cropped the images. Let's apply that

```py
y_hat[:,:,128-(k-1):,:] = 0
y_hat[:,:,:,128-(k-1):] = 0
```

Repeating the calculation you will see that the input is not accurate anymore, so you have to be careful about what you do with your convolution, but in some situations where you can get this to work it will be in fact efficient.

```py
s = 128,128
K_f = torch.fft.rfftn(K, s)
K_f_inv = torch.linalg.pinv(K_f.T).T
y_f = torch.fft.rfftn(y_hat, s)
x_f = torch.einsum('jkxy,ikxy->ijxy', K_f_inv.conj(), y_f)
x_hat = torch.fft.irfftn(x_f, s)
print(torch.mean((x - x_hat)**2) / torch.mean((x)**2))
```

Comment: Why `einsum`? It’s supposed to be an element-wise multiplication.

Comment: No, it is not only an element-wise multiplication, notice the has a reduction on `k`.

Comment: Hi @Bob, thanks for providing such a long and detailed answer! I am trying to understand it. And now I am not sure if the code in the final code block can be directly applied to my original setting (*i.e.*, `kernel size = 3x3` and `padding=1`).

Comment: I may not understand why there are `y_hat[:,:,128-(k-1):,:] = 0` and `y_hat[:,:,:,128-(k-1):] = 0`. I am thinking...

Comment: That's because the conv2d is removing the borders of the result, notice that y planes are 126 x 126.

Comment: I accept this answer. I would particularly appreciate to @Bob for providing such a long answer with detailed explanations.